# A weird error in an implementation of loadDex in android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
char* (*loadDex) (char * dexPath, char * odexPath,int flag) = NULL;

JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    char* (*loadDex) (char *, char *,int) = NULL;
     LOGD("JNI_OnLoad!");
     void *ldvm = (void*) dlopen("/system/lib/libdvm.so", RTLD_LAZY);
     if(ldvm == NULL)
     {
        LOGD("ERROR : %s",dlerror());
        //is art
        void *ldvm = (void*) dlopen("/system/lib/libart.so", RTLD_LAZY);
     }
    loadDex = (char* (*) (char *, char *,int)) dlsym (ldvm, "loadDex");
 void *venv;
     if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &venv, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK)
    {
           return -1;
     }
     return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

I use dlsym() function in order to get the pointer of loadDex() but it returns 0. Anyone here can teach me how to get the exact pointer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`loadDex`](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html#loadDex(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) is a Java method, why are you looking for it in `libdvm.so`?

Comment: so where is loadDex?

Comment: let us take one step back: what are you going to achieve with this method?

Comment: because i wanna modify "loadDex" function. such as argument logging, delete odex file after loaded, etc

Answer (score 2):

`loadDex` was a private API of dalvik and doesn't exist in ART. This sort of thing should just be done in Java.